# After typing Android Keyboard hides

Tags: android, gwt, keyboard

I'm writing a GWT-Web app. Now we are testing this web app on our Android Tablet.

Android 4.2.2
Browser: Chrome 37.0.2062.117

And here is the problem, if we klick into a textbox the keyboard open as expected. But after typing in one or two letters the keyboard hides automaticly.

Then you have to change the text box to get the Keyboard shown again.

Does any one have an idea why this happen ?

Thanks
Dominic

Answer (score 0):

Virtual keyboard doesn't usually hide itself if window receives input focus, but try adding this to your code just to make sure.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```